# angular directive with socket.io updates

Tags: angularjs-directive, socket.io

I would like to ask for your help.
I have:

main.js

```
angular.module('app',['btford.socket-io'])
    .factory('socket', function (socketFactory) {
        var myIoSocket = io.connect('http://localhost');

        var mySocket = socketFactory({
            ioSocket: myIoSocket
        });

        return mySocket;
    })
    .directive('myDir',function(){

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope:{
                marker:'@'
            },
            template: '<p ng-bind="marker"></p><ul><li ng-repeat="item in ItemList"><div ng-bind="item"></div></li></ul>',
            controller:function($scope, socket){

                socket.emit('joinRoom', $scope.marker );

                socket.on('updateEvent',function(data){
                    $scope.ItemList= data;
                });

            }
        };
    })

    .controller('main',function($scope, $http){

        $http.get('localhost/api/getList')
            .success(function(data){
                $scope.markerlist = data;

            });
    });
```

index.html

```
<html lang="en">
    <body  ng-app="app">

        <div ng-controller='main' class="main">
            <div ng-repeat='marker in markerlist'>
                <my-dir marker='{{marker}}'></my-dir>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
        <script src="./libs/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src="./libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./libs/angular-socket-io/socket.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
    </html>
```

how the workflow need to work :

1. open page
2. http service get data from server - list of markers
   ['marker1','marker1','marker1']
3. angular use that data to compile directives
4. each directive join rooms at socket.io server and listen for
   ItemList:

"marker1" join room "marker1" 
"marker2" join room "marker2"
...

5. when some changes io server send ItemList to rooms
6. then io emit data to room "marker1", directive "marker1" receive ItemList only from room "marker1",
   then io emit data to room "marker2", directive "marker2" receive ItemList only from room "marker2" and go on

but at step 6: 
then io emit data to rooms, directive "marker1","marker2","marker3" receive same ItemList, all together,
and data at ItemList rewrites all the time

any suggestions ? %)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

solved by

```
var myIoSocket = io.connect('http://localhost', {'force new connection': true});
```

docs:
https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/wiki/configuring-socket.io